# LINQ group by sum not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0

I have this class:

```
public class tempClass
{
    public int myKey { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}
```

Code to group by and sum:

```
var list = new List<tempClass>();
list.Add(new tempClass { myKey = 1, total = 1 });
list.Add(new tempClass { myKey = 1, total = 2 });
list.Add(new tempClass { myKey = 2, total = 3 });
list.Add(new tempClass { myKey = 2, total = 4 });
list = list
    .Select(w => new tempClass { myKey = w.myKey, total = w.total })
    .GroupBy(x => new tempClass { myKey = x.myKey })
    .Select(y => new tempClass { myKey = y.Key.myKey, total = y.Sum(z => z.total) })
    .ToList();
```

The `list` count is still 4 after the `GroupBy`.

Same result for code below:

```
list = list
    .GroupBy(x => new tempClass { myKey = x.myKey })
    .Select(y => new tempClass { myKey = y.Key.myKey, total = y.Sum(z => z.total) })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `.GroupBy(x => x.MyKey)` don't need to gruop by new object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is that you group by a class which doesn't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. Then the implementation of `System.Object` is used which just compares references. Since all are different references you get one group for every instance.

You could group by this property or override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to compare this property:

```
list = list
    .Select(w => new tempClass { myKey = w.myKey, total = w.total })
    .GroupBy(x => x.myKey)
    .Select(y => new tempClass { myKey = y.Key, total = y.Sum(z => z.total) })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `new { myKey = x.myKey }` is really redundant here.

Comment: @arekzyla: i somehow thought first that he wanted to compare both properties. Edited now

Comment: You can also simplify it to only one method `GroupBy` with it's own selector.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need two `Select` lines, one is enough. And inside `GroupBy`, just select your key, don't create a new object of your class there:

```
list = list
       .GroupBy(x => x.myKey)
       .Select(y => new tempClass { myKey = y.Key, total = y.Sum(z => z.total) })
       .ToList();
```

And here's the declarative-query-syntax version:

```
list = (from x in list
        group x by x.myKey into g
        select new tempClass { myKey = g.Key, total = g.Sum(z => z.total) }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

My, you are creating a lot of new TempClass objects in your LINQ statement, don't you?

The reason that you don't get the correct result is that your GroupBy doesn't make groups of TempClass objects with the equal TempClass.MyKey, but with equal TempClass.

The default EqualityComparer for TempClass declares two TempClass objects equal if they are the same object, thus making two TempClass objects unequal, even if they have the same values.

Your query should be:

```
var result = list
    .GroupBy(listItem => listItem.MyKey) // make groups with equal MyKey
    .Select(group => new                 // from every group make one new item
    {
         Key = group.Key,   // with key the common MyKey in the group
         GrandTotal = group.Sum(groupItem => groupItem.Total);
                            // and value the sum of all Total values in the group
    });
```

I chose not to make the final resulting items a sequence of TempClasses, because I'm not sure if you would consider items with this GrandTotal as TempClass objects. But if you want, you could change the final select:

```
 .Select(group => new TempKey()
 {
     Key = group.Key,
     Total = group.Sum(groupItem => groupItem.Total);
 });
```